# Why is angular loading slowly?

Tags: angular, npm

I have a windows server which runs **angular 4** (with TS of course) and i've noticed that when I enter to the site for the first time in any computer it takes a very long time to load and show the content.

**On Chrome** it can take up to 30-seconds and I don't even want to talk about **Explorer**.

My main page does not do any http calls or db queries, just showing a static content, which is making it even more strange to me.

I don't use **Angular-CLI** and it makes me think that I have some options that I have to change.

In order to run my website I type "**npm run**" in the console, I really don't know what the problem is so if someone would help it will be great !

thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing node.js does some kind of precompiling when you first request a page after server start.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev node.js? why does node.js get involved here?

Comment: What do you think it is that `npm run` does?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev so I would expect it will happen every time, i.e no only the first time which any computer enter the website, but it does not

Comment: Why would you expect that? If it is indeed precompilation, then it's run once, then results are served from cache.